# How can my code do an automatic traversal in different records and transform them to a Hashtbl (type derivation)?

Tags: ocaml

I wish to do traversals on different arbitrary `records` and analyse them and then transform them to a `Hashtbl`. And the code would do it automatically, no matter what `record structure` it is.

---

For example, I want to transform various records (may be different record types) into a hashtable.

say, for a record

```
{
   name = "john";
   age = 50;
}
```

then if I run my code, then this record would be automatically transformed to a `Hashble` which has two {key, value} pairs, {"name", "john"} and {"age", "50"}. Note that here I wish my code can detect `50` is a int, so it would use `string_of_int` to transform it to `string`.

if another record comes, say

```
{
   id = 12;
   type = "book"
   price = 34.5
}
```

then my code would automatically generate a `Hashtbl` - {"id", "12"}, {"type", "book"}, {"price", "34.5"}

---

How can I do that? How can I use code to analyse a record type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [type_conv](https://github.com/janestreet/type_conv) or [deriving](https://github.com/jaked/deriving) tools/frameworks to implement a syntax extension that takes your record type declaration, and generates the expected conversion code (to a hashtable).

Alternatively (and it's a better idea, because much simpler), you could use existing extensions such as [sexplib](https://github.com/janestreet/sexplib) (s-expressions) or, or one of those generating JSON converters, and then work from that representation (s-expressions or JSON) to convert it to a hashtable.

Comment: some functions are do deriving. for example, `Hashtbl.hash` `val hash : 'a -> int
Hashtbl.hash x associates a nonnegative integer to any value of any type. It is guaranteed that if x = y or Pervasives.compare x y = 0, then hash x = hash y. Moreover, hash always terminates, even on cyclic structures.`, so how can these kind of function deal with arbitrary type?

Comment: They are implemented by the runtime, which has some help from the value structure. It is not able to recover the full type information however (`Hashtbl.hash` could not distinguish `[]` from `0` for example).

Answer (score 3):

You can't. 
Due to type safety, OCaml does not have an introspection library.

But there's studies about "runtime type" : http://www.lexifi.com/files/resources/runtime_types.pdf which would permit that.

Note that's the lack of introspection ability is a strong choice of the OCaml compiler team.

Answer (score 1):

Just to say another way what the others have said, a record whose fields are determined at runtime isn't an OCaml record. OCaml has static types, i.e., types that are fixed when the program is written. I think the best way to proceed in OCaml is just to reconceptualize the data as a dictionary, i.e., a dynamic set of name/value pairs. OCaml types for dictionaries are Hashtbl and Map. Now your question is very easy to answer (it seems to me).

Comment: you mean I don't use record, just use Hashtbl?

Comment: ok, i got it, but it is just using record is more convenient for clients

Comment: My suggestion is simply to use a data type on that server that represents what the data actually looks like. If the data is made up of nested name/value pairs, I say use a datatype that looks like that. I haven't used it in OCaml, but I've found JSON to be reasonably nice. There appears to be an OCaml JSON library called Yojson. As gasche suggests, there are probably ways to help clients translate their data to and from JSON.

Comment: sorry, I should have made it clear. I produced a MongoDB driver in ocaml together with a Bson.ml. My clients means the people using my API. for example, I wish my Bson library can accept a arbitrary `record type` and transform it to `bson type`. without this, user has to manually use the current essential api to build their Bson document and the way is just like to build a Hashtbl. writing a record is easy then writing a hashtble, i guess